Query to check status change of an item
I have a table dbo.tblPresentationStatus (SQL script for table at the bottom).
I have to select rows where the status change is wrong. Correct flow
is as below:
Review --> Approve --> Presentation --> Close

From 'Review' the status for a specific presentation ID can change to either 'Approve' or 'Presentation' or 'Close'.
From 'Approve' the status for a specific presentation ID can change to either  'Presentation' or 'Close'
From 'Presentation' the status for a specific presentation ID can change to only  'Close'.
I want to write a query to return presentations with the wrong status flow. So expected output as per records given in script attached should be:



PrID
Status1
Status2
Status3
Status 4




103
REVIEW
PRESENTATION
APPROVE
CLOSE


101
APPROVE
REVIEW
NULL
NULL



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblPresentation

CREATE TABLE #tblPresentation
(
    PrID int NOT NULL,
    PrName nvarchar(100) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #tblPresentation 
VALUES (100, 'PrA'),
       (101, 'PrB'),
       (102, 'PrC'),
       (103, 'PrD')

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblPresentationStatus

CREATE TABLE #tblPresentationStatus
(
    StatusID int NOT NULL,
    PrID int NOT NULL,
    PrStatus nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    StatusDate datetime NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #tblPresentationStatus 
VALUES
    -- PRESENTATION ID 100
    (1, 100, 'REVIEW', '2024-01-01 00:00:00.00'),
    (2, 100, 'APPROVE', '2024-01-02 00:00:00.00'),
    (3, 100, 'PRESENTATION', '2024-01-03 07:00:00.00'),
    (4, 100, 'CLOSE', '2024-01-03 10:00:00.00'),
    
    -- PRESENTATION ID 101
    (5, 101, 'APPROVE', '2024-01-01 00:00:00.00'),
    (6, 101, 'REVIEW', '2024-01-03 10:00:00.00'),  --wrong status change from 'APPROVE' to back ward status of ' REVIEW ' is not allowed
 
    -- PRESENTATION ID 102
    (7, 102, 'REVIEW', '2024-01-01 00:00:00.00'),
    (8, 102, 'PRESENTATION', '2024-01-02 00:00:00.00'),
    (9, 102, 'CLOSE', '2024-01-03 10:00:00.00'),
 
    -- PRESENTATION ID 103
    (10, 103, 'REVIEW', '2024-01-01 00:00:00.00'),
    (11, 103, 'PRESENTATION', '2024-01-02 00:00:00.00'),
    (12, 103, 'APPROVE', '2024-01-03 00:00:00.00'),  --wrong status change from 'PRESENTATION' to back ward status of ' APPROVE' is not allowed
    (13, 103, 'CLOSE', '2024-01-04 00:00:00.00')


What have you tried? Did the answers help you find a solution to your problem?


Define the statuses in the right order
Derive all valid status transitions
Identify invalid status transitions
Get all transitions of presentations with invalid transitions and pivot

-- Define statuses in the right order
CREATE TABLE #tblStatus
(
StatusID int NOT NULL,
PrStatus nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #tblStatus VALUES
(1, 'REVIEW'), (2, 'APPROVE'), (3, 'PRESENTATION'), (4, 'CLOSE')

-- Derive all valid status transitions
select fromStatus.PrStatus FromStatus, toStatus.PrStatus ToStatus
into #ValidTransitions
from #tblStatus fromStatus
cross apply (
    select * from #tblStatus
    where StatusID > fromStatus.StatusID
) as toStatus

-- Identify invalid status transitions
;with StatusTransitions as (
    select *, LAG(PrStatus, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY PrID ORDER BY StatusDate,StatusID) PreviousStatus
    from #tblPresentationStatus
)
select st.*
into #InvalidTransitions
from StatusTransitions st
left join #ValidTransitions vt
    on st.PreviousStatus = vt.FromStatus
    and st.PrStatus = vt.ToStatus
where
    PreviousStatus is not null
    and vt.FromStatus is null

-- Get all transitions of presentations with invalid transitions and pivot
;with AllStatusChangesOfPresentationsWithBadStatusChanges as (
    select PrId, PrStatus, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PrID ORDER BY StatusDate,StatusID) StatusChangeNo 
    from #tblPresentationStatus ps
    where exists(select 1 from #InvalidTransitions where ps.PrID = PrID)
)
SELECT PrId,
    [1] as Status1, [2] as Status2, [3] as Status3, [4] as Status4
FROM AllStatusChangesOfPresentationsWithBadStatusChanges AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(PrStatus) FOR StatusChangeNo IN
    ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;




PrId
Status1
Status2
Status3
Status4




101
APPROVE
REVIEW
NULL
NULL


103
REVIEW
PRESENTATION
APPROVE
CLOSE




I put your flow in order with table variable
DECLARE @StatusFlow TABLE (Id INT,Name nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @StatusFlow (Id, Name)
VALUES (1, 'Review'),(2, 'Approve'),(3, 'Presentation'),(4, 'Close');

After that, just compare the Order Of Flow versus Order Of Row
And show line by line which is the mistake flow
;With T
as
(
select 
        pres.statusID
       ,pres.prID
       ,pres.prStatus
       ,pres.statusDate
       ,flow.id as currentOrderFlow
       ,dense_rank() over (partition by PrID ORDER BY StatusDate, flow.Id) as line
from #tblPresentationStatus pres
inner join @StatusFlow flow on flow.Name = pres.PrStatus
)
select * , (IIF(line <> currentOrderFlow,1,0)) as wrongFlow
From T

Complete flow in db fiddle
db fiddle

As we ask to everyone to not include images in their questions, this also applies to answers

Another way is to string_agg the statusses ordered by the date, and check if they are equal to your expected result
select t.PrID,
       t.PrName,
       t.Statusses
from   ( select p.PrID,
                p.PrName,
                (select string_agg(ps.PrStatus, ',') within group (order by ps.StatusDate)
                 from   tblPresentationStatus ps
                 where  ps.PrID = p.PrID
                ) as statusses
         from   tblPresentation p
      ) t
where  t.Statusses <> 'REVIEW,APPROVE,PRESENTATION,CLOSE'
and    t.Statusses <> 'REVIEW,PRESENTATION,CLOSE'

result is



PrID
PrName
Statusses




101
PrB
APPROVE,REVIEW


103
PrD
REVIEW,PRESENTATION,APPROVE,CLOSE



See this dbFiddle
If you really need the statusses in columns, that requires some work with this approach, see this dbFiddle
Maybe you can improve that using pivot

I suggest creating a explicit table of allowed status changes. Or apply this set of rows as a CTE.
See example
create table #StatusRoute (FromStatus nvarchar(100), ToStatus nvarchar(100));
insert into #StatusRoute values
 ('Review','Approve')
,('Review','Presentation')
,('Review','Close')
,('Approve','Presentation')
,('Approve','Close')
,('Presentation','Close')
;

Or
with #StatusRoute as(
select * from (values
 ('Review','Approve')
,('Review','Presentation')
,('Review','Close')
,('Approve','Presentation')
,('Approve','Close')
,('Presentation','Close')
)sr(FromStatus, ToStatus)
)

select PrId
  ,max(case when rn=1 then PrStatus end) Status1
  ,max(case when rn=2 then PrStatus end) Status2
  ,max(case when rn=3 then PrStatus end) Status3
  ,max(case when rn=4 then PrStatus end) Status4
  ,count(isError)errorQty
  ,string_agg(case when isError>0 then cast(rn+1 as varchar) end,',') ErrorList
from(
  select *
    ,sum(case when PrStatus<>'CLOSE' and nextStatus is not null and ToStatus is null 
           then rn end)
          over(partition by PrId) qtyErrors
    ,case when PrStatus<>'CLOSE' and nextStatus is not null and ToStatus is null 
         then rn 
     end isError
  from(
   select *
     ,lead(PrStatus)over(partition by PrId order by StatusDate) nextStatus
     ,row_number()over(partition by PrId order by StatusDate) rn
   from #tblPresentationStatus 
  )a
  left join #StatusRoute sr on a.PrStatus=sr.FromStatus and a.nextStatus=sr.ToStatus
)b
group by PrId
-- having count(isError)>0
;




PrId
Status1
Status2
Status3
Status4
errorQty
ErrorList




100
REVIEW
APPROVE
PRESENTATION
CLOSE
0
null


101
APPROVE
REVIEW
null
null
1
2


102
REVIEW
PRESENTATION
CLOSE
null
0
null


103
REVIEW
PRESENTATION
APPROVE
CLOSE
1
3



fiddle
Source data for test:



StatusID
PrID
PrStatus
StatusDate




1
100
REVIEW
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000


2
100
APPROVE
2024-01-02 00:00:00.000


3
100
PRESENTATION
2024-01-03 07:00:00.000


4
100
CLOSE
2024-01-03 10:00:00.000


5
101
APPROVE
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000


6
101
REVIEW
2024-01-03 10:00:00.000


7
102
REVIEW
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000


8
102
PRESENTATION
2024-01-02 00:00:00.000


9
102
CLOSE
2024-01-03 10:00:00.000


10
103
REVIEW
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000


11
103
PRESENTATION
2024-01-02 00:00:00.000


12
103
APPROVE
2024-01-03 00:00:00.000


13
103
CLOSE
2024-01-04 00:00:00.000




You may try to number the rows using the appropriate ORDER BY clauses to find the wrong order and PIVOT the results to get the expected output.
; WITH OrderCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        StatusID, PrID, PrStatus, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY PrID 
            ORDER BY StatusID
        ) AS Rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY PrID 
            ORDER BY 
                CASE 
                    WHEN PrStatus = 'REVIEW' THEN 1
                    WHEN PrStatus = 'APPROVE' THEN 2
                    WHEN PrStatus = 'PRESENTATION' THEN 3
                    WHEN PrStatus = 'CLOSE' THEN 4
                    ELSE 5
                END
        ) AS Rn2
    FROM #tblPresentationStatus
), PivotCTE AS (
    SELECT
        PrID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn1 = 1 THEN PrStatus END) AS Status1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn1 = 2 THEN PrStatus END) AS Status2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn1 = 3 THEN PrStatus END) AS Status3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn1 = 4 THEN PrStatus END) AS Status4,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn2 = 1 THEN PrStatus END) AS Correct1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn2 = 2 THEN PrStatus END) AS Correct2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn2 = 3 THEN PrStatus END) AS Correct3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rn2 = 4 THEN PrStatus END) AS Correct4
    FROM OrderCTE
    GROUP BY PrID
)
SELECT PrID, Status1, Status2, Status3, Status4
FROM PivotCTE
WHERE
    ISNULL(Status1, '') <> ISNULL(Correct1, '') OR
    ISNULL(Status2, '') <> ISNULL(Correct2, '') OR
    ISNULL(Status3, '') <> ISNULL(Correct3, '') OR
    ISNULL(Status4, '') <> ISNULL(Correct4, '')


A downvote without an explanation doesn't show why the answer is not useful or wrong. I don't see a problem with this approach.
